# What is the best practice to refer to interface constant within class implementing this interface?

Tags: java, interface, constants

Any constant within an interface is implicitly `public static final`. So **interface constant is a static field.**

If I have a static field `fld` within my class `ExampleCls` then **the best practice to refer to this static field `fld` from any methods (both instance and static) of my regular ExampleCls is through qualified name: `ExampleCls.fld`** - to distinguish using static fields from using instance fields.

So if class `MyCls implements Iface` (some interface with `int MY_CONST=1`) , then `MyCls` inherits this static MY_CONST and **how should I refer to MY_CONST from instance and static methods of `MyCls`?

1. Just like MY_CONST ?
2. Iface.MY_CONST ?
3. MyCls.MY_CONST ?

What is the best accepted practice? And is there any different opinions concerning this issue, or the consensus is generally accepted?

Comment: Instead of `MyCls inherits this static MY_CONST`  I would write `MyCls has accsess to this static MY_CONST`

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: don't.

I think that all current day coding conventions for Java suggest to **not** put *constants* into interfaces. Put them into a class, but don't use the *interface* detour.

Beyond that: if your "environment" still uses interface constants, then use what works best for *you*. In other words: sit down with the people who contribute to this code base, and agree on a common coding convention.

There are no real pressing technical reasons here. This is mere "style only". And in such cases, as said, you simply pick "what works" for you.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you! But the question still remains because language allows it and there are many such uses all around...

Comment: @CodeComplete you're asking for a best practice regarding a bad practice, just don't.